# Update a Field From a Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures

I have a extremely slow query that pulls the total products for every producer in the database. The Producer table only has a count of 1K but the Product table has a count of 50K.

I have created a Stored Procedure to pull back the total Product count for each Producer.

```
/*GET A LIST OF ALL PRODUCERS AND THEIR Product COUNTs */
SELECT p.producer, p.producerID, p.image, p.phone, p.email,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM Product pp
         WHERE pp.producerID = p.producerID) TotalProducts
  FROM Producer p
ORDER BY TotalProducts DESC;
```

Question: How do I then update a new field in the Producer table (totalProducts) for each producerID? Do I need to convert this to a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a multi-table update to generate the value for the column:

```
UPDATE Producer p
JOIN (SELECT producerID, COUNT(*) AS TotalProducts 
      FROM Product
      GROUP BY producerID) pp ON pp.producerID = p.producerID
SET p.TotalProducts = pp.TotalProducts
```

But... if you take this approach you need to update this value every time you `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` rows in the `Product` table (you will need to use triggers to accomplish that).

Your query as it stands doesn't look like it should be particularly slow. Have you checked the output of `EXPLAIN` to make sure it's using indexes appropriately?

Comment: Had no idea about EXPLAIN, so thanks for that. Your query works great but instead of using triggers can we run this as a scheduled EVENT stored proc every few minutes?

Comment: You could run it as a scheduled event; the issue with that is that the data read from the table could be out of date between events.